# Calling a method on a SOAP Web Server with Basic Authentication always return 'faultstring' => 'Forbidden'

Tags: php, authentication, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to call a method on a SOAP Web Server with PHP, but I always get `'faultstring' => 'Forbidden'` as response.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
try {
    $wsdl = 'https://coll.leo-italy.eu/BioGatewayService/wsdl/Aia.BioGateway.Services.BioIZSUMGatewayService.svc?wsdl';
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => 1, 
                                        "exceptions" => 0, 
                                        "login" => 'myusername', 
                                        "password" => 'mypassword', 
                                        "compression" => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP));
    $result = $soap->__call('SetAnalisiIZSUM', array());
    $result2 = $soap->__getLastResponseHeaders();

    var_export($result);
    var_export($result2);

} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    print_r($exception);
}
```

I tried to print the last response headers and this is what I got:

```
'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2021 16:32:40 GMT
Content-Length: 3119
'
```

According to what I understand, this is probably a problem based on how I'm doing the authentication.

I tried to call the method in SOAPUI and it works. So user and password are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Print the request headers of your SoapClient call. Compare those with the request headers of the request that works with SoapUI. See what's different. If you used the right credentials then your call should work.

Comment: I've edited your question to say authentication. Authentication and authorization are different things.

Comment: I compared the two sets of headers and the address of the POST is incorrect, changing it solves the problem. Thanks